# Should I use Get or Load - nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I am wondering which one I should use in this situation. I have a dropdown list that send a value back to the server. The server currently uses load and make the object. It then grabs a value out of and tries to convert it to an enum.

After doing some reading it seems that I should just use Get as I am need to access something out of the object other than the PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, use `Get` if you need access to properties other than the Id itself; this makes the intention of your code much clearer and is likely more efficient in the long run. `Load` is great if you need to setup FK relationships when creating or updating entities without making unnecessary round-trips to the database.

For further reading, check out [Ayende's article](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id) that describes this in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

`Get` and `Load` are different if lazy loading is enabled.
If you use the method `Load`, NHibernate does not retrieve the entity from the database, but rather creates a proxy object and the only populated property is the ID.
If you access to an other property, NHibernate will load the entity from the DB.

So in your case the best use should be Get.